# build steps for javascript/css in heroku python app

Tags: python, web-applications, heroku

I'm working on a Heroku app built in Python, and I can't find a recommended way to add a step to deployment for concatenating/processing/minifying JavaScript and CSS assets. For example, I might like to use tools like r.js or less.

I've seen something called "collectstatic" that Heroku knows to run for Django apps, but my application is using web.py, not Django.

One less-than-perfect approach would be to use these tools locally, on my development machine, to produce combined/compressed static assets. I could then check those compiled files into the git repository and push them to Heroku.

Is there any support for this kind of step built in to Heroku? What is the best way of handling javascript/css files for Heroku web apps in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi/), Heroku lets you run multiple buildpacks. You can either create our own buildpack that only does the asset compilation that you need or find one that already does it and layer it on top of the Python buildpack with buildpack-multi.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Sounds like a complicated process to achieve something that most projects must need eventually.

Comment: The link above is outdated, but see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

Answer (score 0):

I would generally recommend your less than perfect approach, especially if you have a small number of files.

Simplicity is always better than functionality.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll probably just check the locally compiled assets into git for the time being, until it becomes overly burdensome.